# git svn clone without cloning tags

Tags: git-svn

I would like to skip import of all tags. is this the correct syntax?

```
git svn clone "http://svn/svn/IT_Udvikling" git-DataLicense --revision 37000:HEAD --trunk="/FID/DataLicense/trunk" --branches="/FID/DataLicense/branches"  --no-minimize-url --authors-file=../authors-transform.txt
```

I am trying to skip import of tags because the git svn clone process takes forever. it has been running for 3 days now.

Comment: It this a one-time migration, or do you want to commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Comment: It's a one time conversion

Answer (score 0):

The best way to speed up `git-svn` for a one-time migration is to not use `git-svn` at all. Skipping the tags will probably not save you much time, as there are almost no commits that are unique to the tags in a typical SVN repository, just one per tag usually. But yes, if you don't specify `-t` or `--tags` directly or indirectly (e. g. by using `-s` or `--stdlayout`, then no tags should be fetched. But as I said, it will not speed up the process much.

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: (svn2git)[https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git] gem seems to be dead, lots of issues and bugs, 31 open PRs. It fails on macOS as well.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. The `svn2git` you talk about is not the one I talk about which I also describe in my answer. ;-)